# Not sure what's going on here

Tags: android, android-preferences

So I have a SharedPreference I'm calling logged_in. I get the preference and check if it's 1, if it is it's supposed to start the new activity, otherwise I want it to display to me what it actually is. Here's the code:

```
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(this, R.xml.preferences, false);

        prefs = getSharedPreferences("preferences", MODE_PRIVATE);

        // Check if the user is logged in
        String loggedIn = prefs.getString("logged_in", null);

        if(loggedIn != "1") {
            setContentView(R.layout.main);
            TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.login_status);
            textView.setText(prefs.getString("logged_in", null));
        }

        else {
            startActivity(new Intent(this, LoggedInActivity.class));
        }
    }
```

What's really weird is that it will load the main view instead of starting the LoggedIn Activity, but then it displays the logged_in preference as being a 1. So according to what I'm seeing, it should be starting the new activity, but it's not. I'm really confused on this. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are comparing references instead of string values. That is, you are saying *do these two references point to the same object* instead of *are the content of this two objects the same*. You should do instead:

```
if( !loggedIn.equals("1") )
```

Note however that if `loggedIn` is `null`, that code will raise a `NullPointerException`. So this would be more appropriate:

```
if( loggedIn == null || !loggedIn.equals("1") )
```

That said, in this particular case you would be better off by using an `int` preference.

Comment: Oh snap! Thanks to you good sir! I feel like I should have known that. Anyway, won't make that mistake again! Appreciate it!!!